# How do I flip the orientation of a foundation icon

Tags: css, webfonts, glyphicons

I have a foundation-icon which is a magnifying glass oriented from lower left to upper right[image: foundationtion]

This is not how nearly all sites display the icon (normally it is upper left to lower right, e.g., google):

[image: Google search icon]

Is there a method or CSS class to flip this?

Answer (score 1):

```
.logo{
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  filter: FlipH;
  -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

Comment: scaleX(1) is what did the trick for me.

Comment: Cool hope you found it helpful! Weren't sure it worked on 'fonts'?